# "Long-lasted" or "long-lasting" in the mentioned context?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

Individualism lasted from the ancient times to 3 decades ago. Now, should we say

> long-lasted individualism in philosophy

or

> long-lasting individualism in philosophy

The fact that individualism is not lasting anymore makes me think that "long-lasting" is not correct. But then it seems that "long-lasted" is not idiomatic.

Comment: The second sentence is correct. It was long lasting even when it is no longer there.

Comment: **Long-lasting** does not necessarily imply anything about the present. *The invasion of Rome by the barbarian hordes had long-lasting effects.*

Comment: I'm wondering if the -*ing* is what's throwing you. Remember, just because we use -*ing* doesn't mean we are tied to the present. Consider: _I saw six ballerinas dancing yesterday_ – that doesn't mean they are still dancing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of it existing anymore, it was long-lasting when it did.

The second sentence is correct and the first is indeed not idiomatic